# Python Script Not Updating Google Sheets Cell After Dropdown Selection

Tags: python, google-sheets

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import random
import time

# Google Sheets credentials and authorization
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("/home/teto/shaped-kite-414402-072de6ef4591.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Open both spreadsheets
contacts_sheet = client.open('contacts').sheet1
drop_sheet = client.open('drop').sheet1

# Get all the links from contacts spreadsheet
links = contacts_sheet.col_values(1)[1:]  # Exclude header

# Function to update the drop spreadsheet
def update_drop_sheet(name):
    random_link = random.choice(links)
    drop_sheet.update('B1', random_link)
    print(f"Random link for '{name}' added to B1")

# Main function to listen for changes in A1 cell and update B1
def main():
    previous_name = None
    while True:
        cell = drop_sheet.acell('A1', value_render_option='UNFORMATTED_VALUE')
        name = cell.value
        if name != previous_name:
            if name:
                update_drop_sheet(name)
            previous_name = name
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have two Google Sheets spreadsheets named "contacts" and "drop".
The "contacts" spreadsheet contains a list of links in column A.
The "drop" spreadsheet has a dropdown menu in cell A1, where users can select a name.
My Python script is supposed to listen for changes in cell A1 of the "drop" spreadsheet, and when a new name is selected, it should randomly select a link from the "contacts" spreadsheet and update cell B1 with that link.

I've verified that my script has the correct credentials, and the dropdown menu in the "drop" spreadsheet is set up properly. However, when I select a name from the dropdown, the link in cell B1 doesn't get updated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aUmsJoY73SQme1CHurze0fc7kid2PbYcyR-Pg-YSkzo/edit#gid=1143796227

Comment: You may consider using the `Google Apps script` using `On Edit Trigger` for your concern which will also be easier for you to achieve your goal.